# Installation/Uninstallation with UAC enabled for Windows 7 and Vista

Tags: nsis

i am using NSIS(HM NISedit 2.0.3  for editor) for building setup(s) of my application. For Windows with UAC ( 7 and vista) it sometimes does not install until i right click on mysetup.exe and say run as administrator(same is the case for uninstallation).This does not happen when i turn the UAC off. Please suggest me how to disable the UAC within my script before installation proceeds OR anyother way to overcome this UAC issue?. 
  Kindly suggest some solution for the above issue i am currently facing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need admin rights you should use requestexecutionlevel to mark the installer (If you install into $programfiles or write to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE):

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin ;Require admin rights on NT6+ (When UAC is turned on)

!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
UserInfo::GetAccountType
pop $0
${If} $0 != "admin" ;Require admin rights on NT4+
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"
    SetErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
    Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

If you are installing for the current user only ($appdata/$localappdata and HKEY_CURRENT_USER) you can just use `RequestExecutionLevel user`

Comment: Does this trigger the UAC popup and ask for admin password, and if entered, continues with the install. Or does it simply quit if the installer was not run with admin privileges?

Comment: @didibus The "RequestExecutionLevel admin" part adds the manifest bits that UAC checks for, so yes, this triggers the UAC prompt...